# Do the Spring Framework, Boot etc. have ECCN classifications?

Tags: spring

I need to know whether the Spring Framework or any of the other projects e.g. Boot have ECCN classifications.

And would also like to know whether a table of Spring projects vs. ECCN exists.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official communication from Spring Community.

The fact is Spring frameworks have no entry in the Commerce Control List (CCL) so they have no Export Control Classification Number (ECCN).

They are designed as EAR99.